# What a measure of velocity in Box2d?

Tags: box2d, box2d-iphone

What a measure of velocity in Box2d (iPhone, C++)?

When we use command `body->GetLinearVelocity()`, what measure we get? (example, km per hour or meteres per second)

Comment: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=box2d+measure+units&oq=box2d+measure+units&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_l=hp.3...1147l10215l0l10558l19l19l0l0l0l0l200l2285l3j15j1l19l0.eqn%2Cfixedpos%3Dfalse%2Cboost_normal%3D20%2Cboost_high%3D1000%2Ccconf%3D0-95%2Cmin_length%3D2.1.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e2ea4b53f91d9d2d&biw=1687&bih=1106

Answer (score 1):

Box2d is in a MKS system, which means Meter-Kilogram-Second.
So the measure must be m/s.